# 'ReferenceError: document is not defined' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm trying to integrate Mocha into my app, but am getting `document is not defined` error. I've also tried to integrate JSDOM to resolve this but no luck there. Perhaps my implementation is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm testing this locally, but will host this on Amazon EC2 later. Would the document error go away on it's own when hosted live on a server?

**test.js**

```
var test = require('../index.js');
var assert = require('assert');
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom');

global.document = jsdom();

describe('Mutliply', function() {
  jsdom();
  it('should equal 9 when multiply is called', function() {
    assert.equal(9, test.multiply());
  });
});
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

let test = {};

let movieList = document.getElementById('movie-list');
//bunch of code

test.multiply = function() {
  return 3*3;
}

module.exports = test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're `require`ing the code that uses `document` in the global scope before you declare the document.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom');

global.document = jsdom();

var test = require('../index.js');

describe('Mutliply', function() { ...
```

should work, or even

```
var assert = require('assert');
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom');

global.document = jsdom();

describe('Mutliply', function() {
  var test = require('../index.js');  // late import
  it('should equal 9 when multiply is called', function() {
    assert.equal(9, test.multiply());
  });
});
```

Comment: Importing it later did solve the document is undefined issue but now, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined`. It sounds like document is still undefined.

Comment: Well, mocha-jsdom's readme says it's deprecated - maybe try https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global which is linked there?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [JSDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to add Dom support to Node:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.document = new JSDOM(html).window.document;
```